# Send Files to Microsoft Teams using WebHook

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

A while ago I wrote a Powershell module to send notifications to Microsoft Teams:

https://github.com/mhouston100/PSMicrosoftTeams

Works like a charm. Right from the outset, one of the most requested features has been to attach files to the notifications.

Does anyone have any idea, information, documentation etc for attaching files through the 'Incoming Webhook' connector?

I've tried embedding Base64 encoded content directly in the notification etc but it doesn't seem to be the right wau

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Connectors only support [MessageCard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/actionable-messages/message-card-reference) format. Attachments are not supported. You can use Bots to [send or receive files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-files) to user.

Comment: Ahh, disapointing, even the bot method is limited to existing sharepoint/onedrive files. I may just have to use a file share and UNC link. Thanks for taking the time.